# Limit timestamp column between 2 durations in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
df = {'location_id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
      'timestamp':['2020-05-26 06:00:00','2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', 
                 '2020-05-26 10:00:00','2020-05-26 11:00:00','2020-05-26 12:00:00', '2020-05-26 13:00:00',
                 '2020-05-26 06:00:00','2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', 
                 '2020-05-26 10:00:00','2020-05-26 11:00:00','2020-05-26 12:00:00', '2020-05-26 13:00:00',
                 '2020-05-26 06:00:00','2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', 
                 '2020-05-26 10:00:00','2020-05-26 11:00:00','2020-05-26 12:00:00', '2020-05-26 13:00:00',
                 '2020-05-26 06:00:00','2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', 
                 '2020-05-26 10:00:00','2020-05-26 11:00:00','2020-05-26 12:00:00', '2020-05-26 13:00:00',
                 '2020-05-26 06:00:00','2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', 
                 '2020-05-26 10:00:00','2020-05-26 11:00:00','2020-05-26 12:00:00', '2020-05-26 13:00:00']
     }
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Each location_id has a timestamp from 2020-05-06 06:00:00 till 2020-05-26 13:00:00.
What I am trying to achieve is to limit the timestamp of every location_id so that all ids will have a timestamp only between 07:00:00 and 10:00:00.

Final dataframe should be the following:

```
df = {'location_id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5],
      'timestamp':['2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', '2020-05-26 10:00:00',
                   '2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', '2020-05-26 10:00:00',
                   '2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', '2020-05-26 10:00:00',
                   '2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', '2020-05-26 10:00:00',
                   '2020-05-26 07:00:00','2020-05-26 08:00:00', '2020-05-26 09:00:00', '2020-05-26 10:00:00']
     }
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

What I tried so far is the following:

```
dataframe[(dataframe['timestamp'] >= '2020-05-26 07:00:00') & (dataframe['timestamp'] <= '2020-05-26 10:00:00')]
```

In this example it works, but when applying it on the large dataset it is not giving me the correct answer. I tried to sort the values based on the location_id and timestamp and then applied the same condition and still it didn't work.It's always taking the entire dataframe. How can this be achieved ? Note that this was an example taken from a very large dataset.(13,000,000 rows and 2 columns and the real timestamp is between 2020-05-26 00:00:00 till 2020-07-05 23:00:00 for each location_id). I would really appreciate it if someone can give me a solution :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_index` on your time column and use `between_time`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])

print (df.set_index("timestamp").between_time("07:00","11:00"))

                     location_id
timestamp                       
2020-05-26 07:00:00            1
2020-05-26 08:00:00            1
2020-05-26 09:00:00            1
2020-05-26 10:00:00            1
2020-05-26 11:00:00            1
2020-05-26 07:00:00            2
2020-05-26 08:00:00            2
2020-05-26 09:00:00            2
2020-05-26 10:00:00            2
2020-05-26 11:00:00            2
2020-05-26 07:00:00            3
2020-05-26 08:00:00            3
2020-05-26 09:00:00            3
2020-05-26 10:00:00            3
2020-05-26 11:00:00            3
2020-05-26 07:00:00            4
2020-05-26 08:00:00            4
2020-05-26 09:00:00            4
2020-05-26 10:00:00            4
2020-05-26 11:00:00            4
2020-05-26 07:00:00            5
2020-05-26 08:00:00            5
2020-05-26 09:00:00            5
2020-05-26 10:00:00            5
2020-05-26 11:00:00            5
```